# Generate new .bib file from multiple .bib files (or .tex file?)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, revtex

I am writing an article using RevTex4-2, where I reference from 10 individual `.bib` files (separated by topic). This works beautifully.

However, I would like to extract only the references I need from these 10 `.bib` files and place them in a single `.bib` file. Is there an automatic way to do this?

Is it possible to generate a **new** `.bib` file containing only these .bib entries from, say, my `.tex` document?

Comment: @moewe Thank you for the edit!

Comment: Please consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with `bibexport`.  The workflow to create a new bibTeX file with only the items cited in a document is

```
pdflatex filename
bibexport filename
```

Where `filename` is the name of the tex file without extension. `bibexport` operates on the `.aux` file (this is why one has to run `latex` first).

For the full documentation of `bibexport` run

```
texdoc bibexport
```

from a terminal or command line.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer!
Unfortunately, the generated document is blank. The following error messages are in  the terminal:
cat: filename.aux: No such file or directory
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: bibexp.1611482776.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibexp.1611482776.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bibexp.1611482776.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bibexp.1611482776.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: You have to run `latex` (`pdflatex`) first and then `bibexport`.

Comment: Thanks, @Guido! This worked perfectly. ^-^